# How to Migrate a Model on a separate schema

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following class which I want to perform a database migration on using EF6 in a different schema.

```
namespace AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Models
{
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
    }

    public class SignalRUser
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
    }

    public class Connection
    {
        public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public bool Connected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I ran Add-Migration SignalRModel but SignalRModel is just the name of the Migration and then it wants me to work with dB columns:

```
public partial class SignalRModel : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }
```

How do I do a Migration to get that model into the database?

Comment: is this whole thing a code-first database? (Do you have a __MigrationHistory table?)

Comment: It stared with a Generate Model from Database. Ho9wever, there is a _MigrationHistory table

Comment: Have you seen [Entity Framework Code First Migrations with an existing database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398)? Make sure to `Enable-Migrations` and decide if you're starting from an initial schema (db first) or blank (using the existing as a template, but moving forward from there)

Comment: Migrations are enabled (my team member did some) but I don't know what to do? How I can I have a Migration that uses that model to apply to the db?

Answer (score 2):

Based on our quick twitter chat, I think what you are looking for is EF6's new capability to handle multiple contexts per database. The key is that you need to identify the schema name of a context with HasDefaultSchema. Rather then rewrite the whole thing here in StackOverflow, I hoe it's okay to point to existing content. Here are the specs that explain how it works: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations.
Here's a blog post I wrote about using the feature ..specifying the contexts, pointing to the same database,  enabling migrations for each model separately  and adding /executing mingrations against the two models. http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/digging-in-to-multi-tenant-migrations-with-ef6-alpha/

I highly recommend NOT using automatic migrations and following the path of "code-based" migrations.

Comment: Where's the blog post? :)

Comment: whoops, forgot to paste it. fixed.

Comment: half of this conversation is on twitter. You asked (on twitter) if you need to have started with code first. YOu can create a code first based model from an existing db so I'm not sure what you have. Are you using the designer or not? If not, you are using code first and you can use migrations even if you started by regenerating an existing database

Comment: If the answer is yes...you are using edmx and the designer, then you can't use migrations. (They are called "code first migrations", btw) there is nothing in EF designer to let you migrate the db based on  changes in the model. Maybe someone has written a tool.